# Find result in row 1 based on contents of table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am having difficulties finding a solution for the following:

In A2:A15, I have a list of given tasks.
In B1:Z1, I have dates.
In B2:Z15, I have written '1' to indictate when that task will be worked on.

An example of this sheet, can be seen here on the 'Database' tab:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HpfgRMYJqaID8dfoSrXZ7-1vN9yL_e2LH1K92zSYuLA/edit?usp=sharing

What I would like to do with this is conduct a search of this tab so by searching for a task, the search will be able to find the first 1 (i.e the column of the start date for that task), and then return the result in row 1 for that column.

I have created a mock results list shown in the 'Search' tab in the link above.

Any help that can be provided for this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Start Date";IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,{Database!A2:A,INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(Database!B2:Z,Database!B1:Z1,)),,9^99))," "),,1)},2,0))})
```

Which i placed in B1 on the new tab called MK.Help

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect!